# a minimum of a function and continuous function

Tags: functions, continuity, infinity, monotone-functions

I'm not sure if $f(0)$ is a minimum of the function:
$$
f(x)= \begin{cases}
x^2(\sin\left(\frac 1x\right)+1) & \text{for } x\ne0, \\
0 & \text{for }x=0
\end{cases}
$$

and if this is a good example of why if $f$ is continuous on $I$ plus $x_1\in I$ and $f(x_1)$ is a minimum of $f$ then there is a right neighborhood of $x_1$ in which $f$ is increasing?

Comment: We have $-1\le\sin{(1/x)}\le1$ so the function is non-negative and hence this is indeed a minimum of $f(x)$ (there are infinitely many minimum values).

Comment: First of all, thank you. secondly, got it and therefore the statement that I wrote afterwords is true also?

Comment: It is not true! You just gave an example where there are minimisers arbitrarily close to $0$, so it cannot be increasing on any interval containing $0$!

Comment: oh you are right. it is exactly the counterexample for this. thank you so much for explaining.